# Mismatch in Namespaces in xml and xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I have a xsd file for a service in which the namespace is defined on top level as -

```
<xs:schema 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace= "http://www.ycompany.net/" 
xmlns="http://www.ycompany.net/" 
elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

And then there are no namespaces in the whole xsd.

But if I see the XML response of this service, the names of the parameters are correct but there are whole different namespace on each and every element. e.g.

```
<a:getScooterListResponse xmlns:a="http://com/ngr/pumba/vip/service/ycompany/grammars/pclst" xmlns:b="java:ycompany.grammars.pclst.structures.messages" xmlns:c="java:ycompany.grammars.pclst.structures.groups" xmlns:d="java:ycompany.grammars.pclst.structures.segments" xmlns:e="java:ycompany.grammars.pclst.structures.composites" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <a:return>
        <b:OrFiltersQuery>
            <c:Dummy>
                <d:DummyByte>0</d:DummyByte>
            </c:Dummy>
            <c:AndFiltersQuery>
                <c:ScooterListFilterName>
                    <d:AttributeDetails>
                        <e:AttributeType>FQA</e:AttributeType>
                    </d:AttributeDetails>
                </c:ScooterListFilterName>
            </c:AndFiltersQuery>
        </b:OrFiltersQuery>
.
.
.
```

My question is that is it somehow possible to have different namespaces in xsd and actual response or is this xml for a different xsd?

Comment: It's very possible if no one validates the XSD.  Or if there are `xsd:any` elements in the schema.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256043(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As a note this looks to be a serialized soap message and not the XML described by your XSD.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us the whole of the schema (the schema document may import other schema documents for different namespaces), but judging from what you have shown us, this is not the right schema for this instance document.